# Why is my float division off by 0.00390625?

Tags: c

```
float a=67107842,b=512;
float c=a/b;
printf("%lf\n",c);
```

Why is `c` 131070.000000 instead of the correct value 131070.00390625?

Comment: Floating point numbers are not that accurate.

Comment: You should read this: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html before doing any more work with floating point maths.

Comment: If you have no reason good enough for using `float`, always prefer `double`. A good enough reason **is not** "because they're faster" (mostly false); or "because they're smaller" (mostly true); "or because double takes 6 chars and float takes 5".

Comment: @pmg: wow that third reason is the best of all! At least it's true.

Comment: @pmg: I disagree. Using *doubles* isn't better, it just hides bugs longer. Either you know what you do and you know when to use *floats* or *doubles*, or you should consider using a decimal numbers library.

Comment: @Georg: At least `double` can store any `int` on "normal" systems. `float` can't even do that...

Comment: @Georg: what I mean is that as a matter of principle, if you figure you need a floating point number your first option should be `double`. Then, if you know what you're doing ... consider other options; *for example: to calculate the average monthly temperature, `double` is fine*

Comment: @Georg:  Decimal floating point is not intrinsically more precise than binary FP.  For example you still cannot precisely represent PI or 1/3. It does avoid conversion artefacts when displaying decimal values, and typically a library implementation will support rather larger and therefore more precise types that built-in FP.

Comment: @pmg:  Sometimes those reasons are 'good enough' (at least the first two).  In an embedded system with no FPU, no cache, and limited memory (a typical ARM7 micro controller for example), a double precision operation can take twice as long to calculate and twice as long to move operands and results in and out of memory.  On 8 or 16 bit systems, it is even worse, and fixed-point arithmetic is often preferable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your compiler's `float` type is probably using the 32-bit IEEE 754 single-precision format.

67107842 is a 26-bit binary number:

```
  11111111111111110000000010
```

The single-precision format represents most numbers as `1.x` multipled by some (positive or negative) power of two, where 23 bits are stored after the binary place, with the leading `1.` being implied (very small numbers are an exception).

But 67107842 would require 24 bits after the binary place (to be represented as `1.111111111111111000000001` multipled by 2<sup>25</sup>).  As there is only room to store 23 bits, the final `1` gets lost.  So it is the value in `a` that is wrong in this case, not the division - `a` actually contains 67107840 (`11111111111111110000000000`), which is exactly 131070 * 512.

You can see this if you print `a` as well:

```
printf("%lf %lf %lf\n", a, b, c);
```

gives

```
67107840.000000 512.000000 131070.000000
```

Answer (score 7):

Try changing a and c to be type "double", rather than float.  That will give you better precision / accuracy.  (Floats have about 6 or so significant digits; doubles have more than twice that.)

Answer (score 0):

A `float` typically uses 32bit IEEE-754 single precision representation, and is good for only approximately 6 significant decimal figures.  A `double` is good for 15, and where supported an 80 bit `long double` gets to 20 significant figures.

Note that on some compilers there is no distinction between `double` and `long double`, or even no support for `long double` at all.

One solution is to use an arbitrary-precision numeric library, or to use a decimal-floating point library rather then the built-in binary floating point support.  Decimal floating point is not intrinsically more precise (though often such libraries support larger, more precise types), but will not show up the artefacts that occur when displaying a decimal representation of a binary floating point value.  Decimal floating point is also likely to be much slower, since it is not typically implemented in hardware.