# Float Rounding In Objective C

Tags: objective-c, floating-point

I'm currently coding a calculator in Objective-C for an iPhone app. I'm trying to round the output floats to the nearest hundredths place. So if I've got a number that's 1.755, I want it to display 1.76.

The code I'm using currently for this is below.

```
    output.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", outputVariable];
```

So, my question is, how can I get this to display out to the hundredths place, and keep my rounding consistent? "%.2f" has a tendency to round and display in whichever direction it want to at the time, and I need a bit more accuracy than that.

Comment: It's the same as with C.

Comment: So what's the problem/outcome of this?

Comment: (One wonders why you're rounding to a 1/3rd boundary.)

Comment: Why are you adding the roundf() call? Doesn't the `%.2f` give you what you want?

Comment: The problem is in using the a float my and just using "%.2f" it has a tendency to be off by .01 in either direction. Since the calculator has 3 views, I need each view to be consistent and the output on each view needs the same value.

Comment: What's output supposed to be? by saying output.text, it makes sense that you're trying to do a NSString. However, you then turn around and use it in your equation (3.f * output). I'd suggest casting output to a float first (assuming its a number and not a string), then do the calculation. BTW: "For better accuracy, try using double instead. Double does encounter the same problems, but with better precision. Floats have about 6 significant digits; doubles have more than twice that."; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9328260/converting-nsstring-to-float-adds-in-decimal-places

Comment: 1) Use double.  2) Don't round to a .33333 boundary first.

Comment: @kgdesouz thanks a ton, I'll check this out and see if it does anything for me.

Comment: “%.2f” does not round arbitrarily. If you observe the result to be “off”, it is almost certainly because you have passed data that is off. You should show a [self-contained compilable example](http://sscce.org).

Comment: He's right that it rounds arbitrarily. Objective C references the [IEEE printf spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html) which says: _The low-order digit shall be rounded in an implementation-defined manner._

Comment: Just do this: `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", output]`.  Your "rounding" is what's screwing things up.

Comment: @Barmar: The fact that IEEE 1003.1 grants implementations the leeway to round in various ways does not mean the iOS implementation uses that leeway. The rounding in iOS is not arbitrary, and it certainly does not “display in whichever direction it want to at the time”.

Comment: The most likely issue here is that the code is using floats when it means to use `NSDecimalNumber`. If you want to do calculations in decimal (rather than binary), then you can't use floats.

Comment: The issue is that he does the bogus round to 0.33333.. boundary before attempting to format the number.

Comment: With `outputVariable = 1.755f`, `roundf(3.f * outputVariable) / 3.f` is (approximately) 1.666667, and the `%.2f` format should give `1.67` - which is what you wanted. Do you really get a different output?

Comment: @HotLicks problem came long before I tried that. I originally had is set up as [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", output] and, using the example I gave, if I had 1.755 it would round to 1.76 on one of the calculators and then round to 1.75 on the other. I've tried no boundaries and several other types of boundaries, clearly it doesn't work. So I can here looking for other options.

Comment: Have you tried simply adding/subtracting a "small delta" before formatting?  Or rounding the number (correctly) before formatting.  (And be sure to use doubles, not floats.)

Comment: (Why were you rounding to the 0.33333 boundary like that????)

Comment: @HotLicks using doubles now, and I haven't tried either of those, I'll give it a go. Thanks.

Comment: Keep in mind that if you're running everything on iOS and it prints out two different ways using two different sources, the reason almost certainly is that the two values you're printing are DIFFERENT, several decimal places down.  The same formatter is used everywhere in iOS, and I doubt that it varies much (if at all) from version to version on different devices.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the example you give, 1.755. It is impossible for any `float` or `double` object to contain this value, because this value is not representable. The `float` and `double` types use binary floating-point, so all values are the sums of powers of two (including negative powers, such as 1/4 and 2<sup>-10</sup>). 1.755 is not the exact sum of any finite number of powers of two, so it can only be approximated.

In source code that contains `float f = 1.755;` or `double d = 1.755;`, the numeral “1.755” is converted to a representable value. In the `float` case, that results in 1.75499999523162841796875. For `double`, the result is 1.75499999999999989341858963598497211933135986328125.

Note that both of these values are less than 1.755. Therefore, if you round either value to two decimal digits after the decimal place, the result is “1.75”.

If you intend to compute with values such as 1.755 and want them to be exact, then you must use decimal arithmetic or take other steps to avoid errors in floating-point arithmetic (such as scaling the values to be exactly representable, until final output). Specific advice depends on your larger application.

Comment: And then he goes and rounds it to 1.66667.